# How to drop index in mongoose while implementing full text search

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, full-text-search, mongoose-schema

Here is my code

```
` import mongoose from 'mongoose';

let ProductsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userid: { type: String},
    name: { type: String},
    brands: [{ type: String}],
    created: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});


ProductsSchema.index({name: 'text'});  // created index with name`
```

Here I created index with name to implement full text search with name.

my service is

`Product.find({ $text: {$search: searchstring}}).sort({created: -1}).skip(start).limit(limit).exec((err, res) => {   })`

It is working to search with name.

But for another service I want to search with brands. I tried removing name Index and again adding brand index using below code, but didnt work.

```
` 
  ProductsSchema.dropIndex('name_text');
  ProductsSchema.index({brands: 'text'});
`
```

Please help me fix this, how to drop the old index and add a new index using mongoose.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a fantastic idea. Is there some reason why you cannot simply have the index on both? If you really need the separation then I would recommend you use a full blown text search engine like solr or elasticsearch as opposed to dropping indexes on MongoDB continually. It's not really intended for such a case.

Comment: Reason is i had a service where I have to get search results only based on one index 'brands' as mentioned above, so i cant use both indexes.

Comment: Get a separate search engine. The Text facilities in MongoDB ( or the same can be said of most general RDBMS ) are not really made for that sort of thing. Dropping and re-indexing is just going to cause a lot of pain. Best to use a different product for that type of search.

Comment: Can you please give any reference link for method you suggested?

Comment: I gave you two names to search for. Recommendations get stripped from this site pretty quickly,

Comment: Yup thank you so much.